# Font missing in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My website takes lot of time to load and after looking into pingdom, this is what i found:
[image]

It shows few files of 0Byte which take most of the time.
I have reported same issue to Nextend plugin developers too.
What should I add to css ? 
http://animalswecare.com/wp-content/themes/animalswecare/css/style.css

Few of the files size shows 0byte , what can I do to fix it.
Url is wp-content/plugins/nextend-facebook-connect/buttons/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600
On looking for file it shows missing...
How to put font in button folder /public_html/wp-content/plugins/nextend-google-connect/buttons which has file google-btn.css 
http://animalswecare.com/wp-content/plugins/nextend-google-connect/buttons/google-btn.css
In this css i have replaced
     @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);
with 
     @font-face {
     font-family: 'Open Sans';
     font-style: normal;
     font-weight: 600;
     src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'),     url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSnhCUO Gz7vYGh680lGh-uXM.woff) format('woff');
      }

But still issue didn't resolve , am i adding it wrong?

Comment: do you actually HAVE those files on the server? have you tried hitting them directly? are they loading, or 404ing?

Comment: @MarcB They are giving 404

Comment: figure out where those files are being loaded from, figure out where they really are, and fix things...

Comment: @MarcB These are supposed to be in plugin as they belong to plugin, see path of one of these:
http://animalswecare.com/wp-content/plugins/nextend-facebook-connect/buttons/fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600

font awesome path: http://animalswecare.com/wp-content/uploads/font/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css

Comment: yes, "supposed to be". have you checked where they really are? maybe it's something YOU'VE misconfigured.

Comment: @marcB i did check and they are not there...so do i need to upload fonts or is there anyway to use google fonts and get rid of issue..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58173/discussion-between-user995426-and-marc-b).

Comment: If they are not in the folder, upload them to that folder.  It's that simple.